# Using SymmetricDS to connect to a firebird database

Tags: jdbc, firebird, symmetricds

I want to synchronise two databases, one of them being a Firebird database. I am currently trying to use [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/) for this. I am having trouble connecting to a Firebird database, unfortunately:

Firstly, I used Firebird's isql tool to create a new 'empty' database called test.fbd.

I specified the class name for the JDBC Driver in the properties file as follows:
`db.driver=org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver`

I specified the JDBC URL used to connect to the database in the properties file as follows:
`db.url=jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost:<path to database>\TEST.FDB"?encoding=UTF8`

I then test whether I can connect to this firebird database called test.fbd:
`bin/dbsql --engine omni-000`

However, no matter what I do, it throws an exception, saying the database is unavailable.

Below is the full output.

Just a side note - I was able to connect to the test.fbd database using Firebird's isql tool and I could connect to it using DBeaver.

```
[] - AbstractCommandLauncher - Option: name=engine, value={omni-000}
[] - AbstractSymmetricEngine - Initializing connection to database
[] - BasicDataSourceFactory - Setting required database connection property columnLabelForName=true
```

```
An exception occurred. Please see the following for details:
org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLExceptionInfo: unavailable database
[wrapped] java.sql.SQLException: unavailable database [SQLState:08001, ISC error code:335544375]
at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder$Type$1.createSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:532)
at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder.toFlatSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:302)
at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readStatusVector(AbstractWireOperations.java:138)
at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.processOperation(AbstractWireOperations.java:202)
at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readSingleResponse(AbstractWireOperations.java:169)
at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readResponse(AbstractWireOperations.java:153)
at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readGenericResponse(AbstractWireOperations.java:255)
at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version10.V10WireOperations.authReceiveResponse(V10WireOperations.java:60)
at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version10.V10Database.authReceiveResponse(V10Database.java:569)
at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version10.V10Database.attachOrCreate(V10Database.java:111)
at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version10.V10Database.attach(V10Database.java:81)
at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnection.<init>(FBManagedConnection.java:144)
at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(FBManagedConnectionFactory.java:540)
at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBStandAloneConnectionManager.allocateConnection(FBStandAloneConnectionManager.java:65)
at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource.getConnection(FBDataSource.java:124)
at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver.connect(FBDriver.java:137)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
at org.jumpmind.db.util.ResettableBasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(ResettableBasicDataSource.java:72)
[wrapped] java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (unavailable database [SQLState:08001, ISC error code:335544375])
at org.jumpmind.db.util.ResettableBasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(ResettableBasicDataSource.java:78)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at org.jumpmind.db.platform.JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory.determineDatabaseNameVersionSubprotocol(JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory.java:221)
[wrapped] org.jumpmind.db.sql.SqlException: Error while reading the database metadata: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (unavailable database [SQLState:08001, ISC error code:335544375])
at org.jumpmind.db.platform.JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory.determineDatabaseNameVersionSubprotocol(JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory.java:291)
at org.jumpmind.db.platform.JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory.createNewPlatformInstance(JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory.java:176)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.ClientSymmetricEngine.createDatabasePlatform(ClientSymmetricEngine.java:390)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.ClientSymmetricEngine.createDatabasePlatform(ClientSymmetricEngine.java:335)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.AbstractCommandLauncher.getDatabasePlatform(AbstractCommandLauncher.java:408)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.DbSqlCommand.executeWithOptions(DbSqlCommand.java:75)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.AbstractCommandLauncher.execute(AbstractCommandLauncher.java:192)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.DbSqlCommand.main(DbSqlCommand.java:44)</init>
```

Comment: There is a `"` in your URL after the database name, remove it (though AFAIK, Firebird would ignore it). I also assume that `<path to database>` is replaced with the actual path to the database in your actual code. Also consider using the [standard URL format](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#pure-java-default) (`jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/<path-to-database>\TEST.FDB`) instead of this deprecated URL format. The "unavailable database" can occur if you are using an invalid filesystem path (eg on Windows, a non-existent drive letter.

Comment: Is the database file on the local filesystem, or on a network share? What is the actual path of the database?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have tried the deprecated and the new URL format. Both of them throw the same exception. The " in the URL above is something I should have taken out in my question - I placed it there since my path contained spaces. But I tried a path without spaces as well. The other format I tried is as follows: ```jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/<path to database>\test.fbd```.Yes, I just replaced the actual path with <path to database> in this question. And yes, the database is on my local filesystem. The new path I also use in DBeaver and it successfully connects to the database.

Comment: If DBeaver can connect, then so should SymmetricDS, both use Jaybird to connect. You shouldn't use double quotes around the path. Using something like `jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/"<path to database>\test.fdb"` will actually cause an 'unavailable database' error (while only having a trailing `"` seems to work fine). I highly recommend providing a [mre] with the actual path used.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, if `db.url` is in a properties file, then the use of ```\``` must be escaped to ```\\``` otherwise it is dropped (for invalid escapes), or for example `\t` is interpreted as a tab. So  if your path is `C:\data\db\test.fdb`, what is read by Java from the properties file is `C:datadb<tab>est.fdb`. Replace it in your properties file with either `C:\\data\\db\\test.fdb` or use forward slash `C:/data/db/test.fdb`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel OK. So using forwards slashes didn't work initially: ```db.url=jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/C:/Program Files/Firebird/Firebird_2_5/examples/empbuild/EMPLOYEE.FDB?encoding=UTF8```

But it had to work, so I tried to remove the predefined port 3050:```db.url=jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/C:/Program Files/Firebird/Firebird_2_5/examples/empbuild/EMPLOYEE.FDB?encoding=UTF8``` and then it successfully connected.I tried a different port (3051) (which should not work?), and it didn't. (Refused to connect) Perhaps port 3050 is already used, and the driver defaults to another one?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for all the help. If you'd like to submit the answer, I'll mark it answered.

Comment: I closed the question as duplicate of the general question about backslashes in property files, so it is not possible to post an answer anymore. As to the problem with the port, I don't know. Jaybird defaults to port 3050, and it should work both with and without port.